# draw only top n series group in ssrs charts

Tags: c#, reporting-services

if the report dataset contains data on extra hours worked by employees per month , i need to display chart that have X-Axis as years , Y-Axis as number of extra hours , and series groups as working hours of each employee within this year(summation of working hours of months in this year) , but display only the 3 employees with greatest working hours within the chosen time interval . any help?

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the top 3 in the dataset, and give them a value of "1" in a new bit column. Then filter the chart based on that bit column.